# What is the best way to merge two Future[Map[T1, T2]] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of fileNames and I want to load the correlated pages in batches (and not all at once). In order to do so, I'm using `FoldLeft` and I'm writing an aggregate function which aggregates a Future[Map[T1,T2]].

```
def loadPagesInBatches[T1, T2](fileNames: Set[FileName]): Future[Map[T1, T2]] = {
   val fileNameToPageId: Map[FileName, PageId] = ... //invokes a function that returns the pageId correlated to the fileName.
   val batches: Iterator[Set[FileName]] = fileNames.grouped(10) //batches of 10;
   batches.foldLeft(Future(Map.empty[T1, T2]))(aggregate(fileNameToPageId))
}
```

And the signature of aggregate is as follows:

```
def aggregate(fileNameToPageId: Map[FileName, PageId]): (Future[Map[T1, T2]], Set[FileName]) => Future[Map[T1, T2]] = {..}
```

I'm trying to make sure what is the best way to merge these Future[Map]s.

Thanks ahead!

P.S: `FileName` and `PageId` are just Types of string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you have exactly 2 futures, `zipWith` would probably be the most idiomatic.

```scala
val future1 = ???
val future2 = ???

future1.zipWith(future2)(_ ++ _)
```

Which is a shorter way of writing a for comprehension:

```
for {
  map1 <- future1
  map2 <- future2
} yield map1 ++ map2
```

Although `zipWith` could potentially implement some kind of optimization.

Comment: But I have more than 2 maps. Lets say I have 100 files and I'm taking batches of 10. This will mean that I have 10 maps of these batches and 1 empty map that I'm starting with in the `reduceLeft` function.

Comment: I do have only two maps in my subfunction if that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes I mean if you have 2 `Future[Map[A,B]]` locally in your function.

Comment: Thanks.
The first option does work (the second one is not; probably because map2 is not in my for-comprehension, as you can see in my solution).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was putting the two maps into a list and using `Future.reduceLeft`.

```
def aggregate(fileNameToPageId: Map[FileName, PageId]): (Future[Map[T1, T2]], Set[FileName]) => Future[Map[T1, T2]] = {
   case (all, filesBatch) => 
      val mapOfPages: Future[Map[NodeId, T]] = for {
         ... //Some logic
      } yield "TheBatchMap"
      Future.reduceLeft(List(all, mapOfPages))(_ ++ _)
}
```